# How to use method: 'post' to send form data from view to other controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
<%= simple_form_for :addcomments, :url => addcomments_post_path, :multipart => true ,:method => 'post' do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title %>
<%=  f.input :body %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

This is my partial view for adding comment to the post and below is my post->show view

```
<div>
<h4>Comments </h4><br>
<%= @all_comments.each do |t| %>
  <h3><%= t.title %></h3> <br>
  <h4><%= t.body %></h4>   <br>
  <% end %>
  <%= render :partial => 'addcomment' %>
</div>
```

Comments_controller.rb is as

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

# before_filter :load_commentable


def addcomments
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@user = current_user
@comment = Comment.build_from(@post,@user,params[:comment])
if @comment.save
  redirect_to post_url
else
  redirect_to post_url
end
end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
member  do
  post  'addcomments', to: 'comments#addcomments'
end
end
```

When i run this code and clicks on post->show, i got error that

```
The action 'addcomments' could not be found for CommentsController
```

Comment: can you paste your `rake routes` output?

Comment: @Lucas: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=piG8g1nw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using polymorphic model so your first level route should be "posts" instead of "comments".

```
# resources :comments do # Change this line to
resources :posts do
  member do
    post 'addcomments', to: 'comments#addcomments'
  end
end
```

Comment: @AkashShinde, maybe you need to revise the route in form to "addcomment_post_path" according to your `rake routes`. By the way, it seems there are too much settings not in convention, just my feeling.

Comment: rake routes output : pastebin.com/raw.php?i=piG8g1nw

Comment: @AkashShinde, yes I've saw that file before my last comment. You see the right path for 'comments#addcomments', in that file, is `addcomments_post_path`. So you need to revise it in the form accordingly(you called path in form)